# cUrl авторизация VK С++

Tags: c++, curl

Хочу Сделать авторизацию в ВК используя cUrl

```
if (Curl) {
            //устанавливаю параметры
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, "cookie.txt");
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

            //Перехожу по адресу [url]https://login.vk.com/?act=login[/url] и выдергиваю оттуда ip_h ig_h
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.vk.com/?act=login");
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data_str);
    curl_easy_perform(Curl);
    ip_h = GetMARKLink(content, MARKip_h, 0);
    ig_h = GetMARKLink(content, MARKig_h, 0);


         //Далее делаю POST запрос и подставляю туда мыло, пароль ip_h  ig_h
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.vk.com/?act=login");
    URL="&role=al_frame&expire=&captcha_sid=&captcha_key=&_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fvk.com&ip_h=" +
    ip_h+"&lg_h=" + ig_h + "&email=" + escape(Curl, Email) + "&pass=" + escape(Curl, Password);
      curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, URL.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, URL.length());
    curl_easy_perform(Curl);
```

Получаю такую HTML страницу

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
var _ua = navigator.userAgent;
var locDomain = 'vk.com'.match(/[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\.?$/)[0];
if (/opera/i.test(_ua) || !/msie 6/i.test(_ua) || document.domain != locDomain) {
  document.domain = locDomain;
}
parent.__qlClear();
addEvent = parent.addEvent;
vk = parent.vk;
parent.stManager.add(['notifier.js', 'notifier.css'], function() {
  Notifier = parent.Notifier;
    ;(function () {
    var cb = function () {Notifier.init({"queue_id":"events_queue123456789","timestamp":1526695885,"key":"fjJjUNUv9IDm0a7gMc3OMJ1tyDSEshnE9XdaGXx9s7gJA6tdkSRfLTQeV7FZLY8k","uid":"123456789","version":10,"debug":false,"instance_id":"Mzg5MDg0","server_url":"https:\/\/queuev4.vk.com\/im677","frame_path":"https:\/\/queuev4.vk.com\/q_frame.php?7","frame_url":"im677","refresh_url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/notifier.php","fc":{"version":23,"state":null,"state_hash":"1459042426_664369fe6bcce74579"}})}
    if (window.vk && window.vk.loaded) cb(); else addEvent(window, 'DOMContentLoaded load', cb);
  })();
  parent.onLoginDone('/id123456789');
});
</script>
```

И такой HEAD

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache
Date: Sun, 27 Mar 2016 01:33:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/3.22477
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-store
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Set-Cookie: h=1; expires=Fri, 31 Mar 2017 06:04:19 GMT; path=/; domain=login.vk.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: s=1; expires=Mon, 03 Apr 2017 22:48:59 GMT; path=/; domain=login.vk.com; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: l=236834677; expires=Wed, 29 Mar 2017 17:24:28 GMT; path=/; domain=login.vk.com; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: p=aa926cd86686324a2f57b0a308f0d1d70e0b9c3d1d58e92bb001f; expires=Sun, 02 Apr 2017 17:07:05 GMT; path=/; domain=login.vk.com; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: remixq_0b097fbf2a3b86d9c393d6a23dd1c674=db5a2f3ce3ca9211c3; path=/; domain=.vk.com; HttpOnly
Location: [url]https://vk.com/login.php?act=slogin&to=&s=1&__q_hash=0b097fbf2a3b86d9c393d6a23dd1c674[/url]



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Date: Sun, 27 Mar 2016 01:33:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
Content-Length: 1070
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/3.22477
Set-Cookie: remixq_0b097fbf2a3b86d9c393d6a23dd1c674=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixq_0b097fbf2a3b86d9c393d6a23dd1c674=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixlhk=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixreg_sid=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixapi_sid=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixrec_sid=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixsid=1e7fad41aadcebf268650ba63260c51050475ecbd87f5e9637f7e; expires=Mon, 20 Mar 2017 05:58:08 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com; secure
Set-Cookie: remixsslsid=1; expires=Thu, 30 Mar 2017 18:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-store
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
```

Мне кажется проблема кроется в куках.

Comment: Для чего через Curl?

Comment: А как без него?

Comment: Там ведь POSTзапрос нужен